# Why UIWebView does not open my link in Safari?

Tags: ios, swift, safari, uiwebview

I wrote this code:

```
    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)
        return false
    }
```

and it works for all normal URLs. But when I click on the image/gif with the next code:

```
<a href="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*IR7oti7mEsYunzp_HhcNig.gif" 
target="_blank" class="c" 
style="background-image: url('//cdn.iframe.ly/pj?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-images-1.medium.com%2Fmax%2F800%2F1*IR7oti7mEsYunzp_HhcNig.gif&amp;width=1280&amp;
key=9b0e65e32a5412cf736c430972d914c33f46250b&amp;cache=temp');">
1*IR7oti7mEsYunzp_HhcNig.gif </a>
```

it opens this gif/URL in my application, inside of UIWebView.

How can I force that it will open that gif/URL in Safari, too?

Comment: Are you sure that link results in `LinkClicked` navigation type? I would try printing out the `navigationType` - `print("\(navigationType)")` just to make sure it's the expected value.

Comment: @DylanS it prints `Navigation type: UIWebViewNavigationType` =/

Comment: `print("\(navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked)")` It's just printing the type, not the value.

Comment: @DylanS I get false value =/

Comment: There's your problem. Just put a breakpoint in that method, and inspect `navigationType` with the debugger. Figure out what it's supposed to be, and update your code to allow that navigation type.

Answer (score 0):

Something must be broken somewhere else in your code.
Working fine like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var webView : UIWebView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.webView?.loadHTMLString("<a href='https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*IR7oti7mEsYunzp_HhcNig.gif' target='_blank' class='c' style='background-image: url('//cdn.iframe.ly/pj?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn-images-1.medium.com%2Fmax%2F800%2F1*IR7oti7mEsYunzp_HhcNig.gif&amp;width=1280&amp; key=9b0e65e32a5412cf736c430972d914c33f46250b&amp;cache=temp');'> 1*IR7oti7mEsYunzp_HhcNig.gif </a>", baseURL: NSURL(string: "testurl.com"))
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL!)
            return false

        }

    return true
}
}
```

[image: Screenshot with the result]

Comment: My navigation type prints `Navigation type: UIWebViewNavigationType`. I think that's a problem